# Create Azure Devops pipeline without code checkout

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that i use to run scripts for exporting and importing Dynamics solutions between servers. These solution imports/exports dont require any code from a repository. I would like to just run the pipeline without the need to checkout code to speed it up and remove unneccecary steps. Is there a way to do this?

If i am not mistaken, i use the 'classic' versions of pipelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `Don't sync sources` option on the `Get Sources` step:

[image]

Comment: That does it. It completely skips the checkout step. Tha documentation resources of that function where not clear to me, thats why i asked here. Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [classic release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) instead of build pipeline.

Release pipelines do not require any repository to be able to run, as opposed to classic build pipelines and YAML pipelines.

[Screenshot of Azure DevOps menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjHqD.png)